# Calculate the max samples with ramp up

Tags: math, jmeter

I got this math problem. I am trying to calculate the max amount of samples when the response time is zero. My test has 3 samples (HTTP Request). The total test wait time is 11 seconds. The test is run for 15 minutes and 25 seconds. The ramp up is 25 seconds, this means that for every second 2 users are created till we reach 50.

Normally you have to wait for the server to respond, but I am trying to calculate the max amount of samples (this means response time is zero.) How do i do this. I can't simply do ((15 * 60 + 25) / 11) * 50. Because of the ramp up.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Maybe I should translate this problem into something generic and not specific to JMeter So consider this (maybe it will make sense to me aswel ;)). 
50 people are walking laps around the park. Each lap takes exactly 11 seconds to run. We got 15 minutes and 25 seconds to walk as many as possible laps. We cannot start all at the sametime but we can start 2 every second (25seconds till we are all running). How many laps can we run?

What i end up doing was manually adding it all up...
Since it takes 25s to get up to full speed, only 2 people can walk for 900s and 2 people can walk for 901s and 2 people can walk for 902s all the way to total of 50 people..
Adding that number together should give me my number i think.

If I am doing something wrong or based on wrong conclusion I like to hear your opinion ;). Or if somebody can see a formula.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about jmeter, but I do understand your question about people running round the park :-).

If you want an exact answer to that question which ignores partial laps round the park, you'll need to do (in C/java terminology) a for loop to work it out.  This is because to ignore partial laps it's necessary to round down the number of possible laps, and there isn't a simple formula that's going to take the rounding down into account.  Doing that in Excel, I calculate that 4012 complete laps are possible by the 50 people.

However, if you're happy to include partial laps, you just need to work out the total number of seconds available (taking account of the ramp up), then divide by the number of people starting each second, and finally divide by how many seconds it takes to run the lap.  The total number of seconds available is an [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression).

To write down the formula that includes partial laps, some notation is needed:

```
    T = Total number of seconds (i.e. 900, given that there are 15 minutes)
    P = number of People (i.e. 50)
    S = number of people who can start at the Same time (i.e. 2)
    L = time in seconds for a Lap (i.e. 11)
```

Then the formula for the total number of laps, including partial laps is

```
Number of Laps = P * (2 * T - (P/S - 1)) / (2*L)
```

which in this case equals 4036.36.

Comment: I am happy to include partial laps, and your number of 4072 is a number which comes to the right size. But i do not really understand the second part of your answer. Maybe you could elaborate with a tiny example?

Comment: And have you seen my last addition to my question? I that what you mean?

Comment: OK if you're happy to include partial laps I can work out a simple formula for you.  Give me a few minutes!  PS: I was calculating starting two people every two seconds rather than every one second.  So I've corrected it, I now think that the rounded down answer is 4128

Comment: Ok ;) But how did you get that answer ;) or are you still working on the formula? (Not trying to haste you or anything ;)) I am allready appreciating your effort

Comment: I finally got you arithmetic progression comment! Or atleast it starting to become clear to me ;)

Comment: Finally got a minute to post the formula!  Do you think it's right?  Incidentally I've revised my rounded down version to 4012 now, but if partial laps are OK I think it's 4036.36 (to 2 dec places).

Comment: You Sir are Awesome ;) Thanks! I will use it and credit where do!

Comment: I think your formula is inaccurate if `P` is not a multiple of `S`

Answer (score 0):

Assume we're given:

> `T` = total seconds = 925
>   `W` = walkers = 50
>   `N` = number of walkers that can start together = 2
>   `S` = stagger (seconds between starting groups) = 1
>   `L` = lap time = 11
>   `G` = number of starting groups = `ceiling(W/N)` = 25

Where all are positive, `W` and `N` are integers, and `T >= S*(G-1)` (i.e. all walkers have a chance to start). I am assuming the first group start walking at time `0`, not `S` seconds later.

We can break up the time into the ramp period:

> Ramp laps = `summation(integer i, 0 <= i < G, N*S*(G-i-1)/L)`
>   = `N*S*G*(G-1)/(2*L)`

and the steady state period (once all the walkers have started):

> Steady state laps = `W * (T - S*(G-1))/L`

Adding these two together and simplifying a little, we get:

> Laps = `( N*S*G*(G-1)/2 + W*(T-S*(G-1)) ) / L`

This works out to be **4150 laps**.

There is a closed form solution if you're only interested in full laps. If that's the case, just let me know.